# Modulo operator in ERB `each_with_index`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to create a new table-row when the index in `each_with_index` loop is divisible by 4. 
i.e - I want 4 cells in each row.

When I try to do the following, I get `undefined method %` error.

```
<% @brand_promotions.each_with_index do |index, brand_promotion| %>
        <% if (index % 4) == 0 %>
          <div class="row">
        <% end %>
        <div class="col-3">
          Column <%= index %>
        </div>
        <% if (index % 4) == 0 %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is the second parameter

```
<% @brand_promotions.each_with_index do |brand_promotion, index| %>
```